# Cross reference from DSL to EMF Ecore model not working in LSP setup

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-emf, xtend

I have a DSL language where we need to cross-refer EAttribute that are defined in a separate file.
This works fine in the eclipse plugin setup but it is not working in the LSP setup based on Vscode/Theia client.

Grammar Snippet -

```
Atomic returns Expression:
    {IntConstant} value=INT |
    {StringConstant} value=STRING |
    {BoolConstant} value=('true' | 'false') |
    {VariableRef} variable=[ecore::EAttribute|QualifiedName];
```

Example -

1. DSL file - test.mexpression

```
  iota=1
```

2. iota is a variable which is defined in a separate file - variables.ecore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ecore:EPackage xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" name="vari" nsURI="vvvv" nsPrefix="var">
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Variables">
<eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="iota" eType="ecore:EDataType 
 http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EBoolean"/>
<eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="Cars" eType="ecore:EDataType 
http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"
    defaultValueLiteral=""/>
</eClassifiers>
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Car">
<eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="Model" eType="ecore:EDataType 
http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"/>
</eClassifiers>
</ecore:EPackage>
```

Language client Snippet -

```
 export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
     // The server is a started as a separate app and listens on port 5007
     let connectionInfo = {
         port: 5008
     };
     let serverOptions = () => {
         // Connect to language server via socket
         let socket = net.connect(connectionInfo);
         let result: StreamInfo = {
             writer: socket,
             reader: socket
         };
         return Promise.resolve(result);
     };
     
     let clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
         documentSelector: ['mexpression','ecore'],
         synchronize: {
             fileEvents: workspace.createFileSystemWatcher('**/*.*')
         }
     };
     
     // Create the language client and start the client.
     let lc = new LanguageClient('Xtext Server', serverOptions, clientOptions);
```

Am I missing something here ? or We have to create  a standalone setup for variable file & register it via service providers to make it work in LSP environment.

Comment: you need to make sure you provide a language server for ecore. a lightweight solution could be to create a manifest for the org.eclipse.xtext.ecore.EcoreSupport similar as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968029/how-to-implement-the-xtext-xmi-cross-reference-for-lsp-based-editor-in-theia

Comment: Cross-referencing is working but workspace manager is throwing below error while saving variable file -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl and org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.WorkspaceManager.doRead(WorkspaceManager.java:436)
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl$1.lambda$doRead$1(LanguageServerImpl.java:1093)
 at

Comment: yes you may have to work around this. (dont know what exact line 1093 does in your Xtext version)

Comment: Xtext version being used - 2.23.0.v20200831-0745
Code at line 1093-
 return requestManager.runRead(cancelIndicator -> workspaceManager.doRead(uriExtensions.toUri(uri),
     (document, resource) -> function.apply(new ILanguageServerAccess.Context(resource, document,
       workspaceManager.isDocumentOpen(resource.getURI()), cancelIndicator))));
Code at line 436 causing exception within doRead-
XtextResource resource = (XtextResource) projectMnr.getResource(resourceURI);

Comment: i still dont see which service is calling this.

Comment: Stack trace -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl and org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.WorkspaceManager.doRead(WorkspaceManager.java:436)
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl$1.lambda$doRead$1(LanguageServerImpl.java:1093)
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.concurrent.ReadRequest.lambda$doRun$0(ReadRequest.java:66)

Comment: Adding more details -
On save of variable file a build is run which is initiating the doRead method of WorkspaceManager.Flow-
Variable File save -> LanguageServerImpl(afterBuild) ->LanguageServerImpl.access(doRead) ->RequestManager(runRead)->WorkspaceManager(doRead)

Comment: from this i still dont get: why is doRead called, why is there not the internal build only? did you configure the client to know the ecore file extension?

Comment: Added the language client code in the question section.

Comment: Getting Same error even when I hover over conetnts in XMI variable file -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceImpl and org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.WorkspaceManager.doRead(WorkspaceManager.java:436)
 at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl.hover(LanguageServerImpl.java:713)

Comment: my proposal was not to add ecore in the client but just ship it. dont know if this works with changes. with a client working on ecore you need to adapt all the code that cannot deal with it.

Comment: you may file an enhancement request at github.com/eclipse/xtext-core. but i have doubts we will find the time to fix it soon. i also have no clue how to properly implement stuff like content assist and co

Comment: maybe you also can configure the clent to notifiy the server via didChangeWatchedFiles and not do contant assist and co for ecore

Comment: If we do not register variable file in the language client then changes/updates to the file are not reflecting on LanguageServer.

Comment: thus the question if you can look into didChangeWatchedFiles

Comment: I don't need content assist or co on variable file, but it is failing on file save as well. Though I don't know much about didChangeWatchedFiles but will give it a go.